# hyperlinking from pdf to word bookmarks

Tags: pdf, microsoft-word-2007, bookmarks

I have a word document(2007) that has links to bookmarked locations in a different word document. Call them document A and B respectively.  As word docs the linking works fine.

But when I PDF document A, the link tries to open a web page.  If I remove the bookmark and only link to document B, it works fine when I pdf document A. The problem is with the bookmark.  Any ideas?

"how do you take a word document with book marks to a different word document, pdf it and have those bookmarks still take you to the bookmarked location in the the word document?"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the link is being encoded with the PDF Action type "URI" instead of "Launch" which would open the program in the appropriate application. You can test if this is the case by opening your PDF in any hex editor and replacing the appropriate instance of `/Type/Action/S/URI/URI(path)` with `/Type/Action/S/Launch/F(path)`.

If this resolves the issue then you may need to try produce the PDF using a different application which does not write the links like this, or alternatively post process your document using the method above.